# jquery value of global variable is not coming when its execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

this below code runs, but, my problem, for the variable 'cc', i unable to get the value. when page loads, i created element 'input' assigning this into global variable 'globalVar', my problem is not able get value of the global variable 'globalVar', pls see the code, you can have some idea. Any help? it would be more helpful.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>eq demo</title>
<style>
div, .sectiontitle {
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
margin: 10px;
float: left;
border: 2px solid blue;
}
.blue {
background: yellow;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="mainnav" id="mainnav1"><li><a href="/Home.aspx"><span>Home</span></a></li><li><a href="/Test-Orders/Home.aspx"><span>Test orders</span></a></li><li><a href="/Access-Arrangements/Home.aspx"><span>Access arrangements</span></a></li><li><a href="/Pupils/Home.aspx"><span>Pupil registration</span></a></li><li><a href="/Teacher-Assessment/Home.aspx" class="active"><span>Teacher assessment</span></a></li><li><a href="/Pupil-results/Home.aspx?stage=2"><span>Pupil results</span></a></li><li><a href="/Phonics/Home.aspx"><span>Phonics screening check</span></a></li></ul></div>
<div></div>
<div class="sectiontitle clearfix"><p class="breadcrumb"><a href="/Home.aspx">NCA tools</a><a href="Home.aspx">Teacher assessment</a></p></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>


<script>
            window.globalVar = "";

            globalVar = document.createElement("input");
            globalVar.id = "li2";
            globalVar.type = "text";

            $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#mainnav1 li a").click(function (e) {

                    globalVar.value = $(this).find('span').text().toLowerCase();
                    //alert(globalVar); //here, the value is coming
                    return globalVar;
                });

                var headerHighlightMap = {
                    "nca tools": "home",
                    "test orders": "test orders",
                    "access arrangements": "access arrangements",
                    "pupil registration": "pupil registration",
                    "teacher assessment": "teacher assessment",
                    "pupil results": "pupil results",
                    "phonics screening check": "phonics screening check"
                };

                var currentHeaderText = $.trim($(".sectiontitle h1").html()).toLowerCase();
                var currentHeaderTextsel = $.trim($(".sectiontitle p.breadcrumb a").eq(1).html()).toLowerCase();
                $.each($("#mainnav1 li"), function (index) {
                    var cc = globalVar.value;
                    alert(cc);
                    var currentElemSpanObj = $($(this).find("span"));
                    var headerInFocus = $.trim(currentElemSpanObj.html()).toLowerCase();
                    //alert(headerInFocus);
                    if (headerHighlightMap[currentHeaderText] == headerInFocus) {
                        currentElemSpanObj.addClass("blue");
                    }
                    else if (headerHighlightMap[currentHeaderTextsel] == headerInFocus) {
                        currentElemSpanObj.addClass("blue");
                    }
                    else if (headerHighlightMap[globalVar.value] == headerInFocus) {
                        currentElemSpanObj.addClass("blue");
                    }

                    else {
                        currentElemSpanObj.removeClass("blue");
                    }
                });
            });
            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe because it doesn't have any value ultil you click on `#mainnav1 li a` element ;)

Comment: Hi i am looking for some help on this. any help would be appreciate. please

Comment: your issue is because when you do the `alert` in the `each` instruction,`globalVar.value` doesn't have any defined value at all...